# ListView in QML - empty rows

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I see the list, it has right amount of the rows(acording to the elements amount in the QStringList), but rows are empty.

What am i doing wrong?

in c++ my code is:

```
QStringList s;
s.append("1");
s.append("2");
s.append("2");
s.append("2");
s.append("2");
s.append("2");


QObject * pList = pQmlObject->findChild<QObject*>("devicesList");
pList->setProperty("model",s);
```

and in QML i do:

```
 ListView {
            id:devicesList
            objectName:"devicesList"
            width: 100; height: 100
            model: myModel
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 50

                width: 100

            }
        }
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: AFAIK delegate must be *Item* or *Component*

Comment: @danielfranca `Rectangle` is an `Item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the text for that `ListView`. In your case:

```
ListView {
            id:devicesList
            objectName:"devicesList"
            width: 100; height: 100
            model: myModel
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 50
                width: 100
                Text { text: modelData }
            }
        }
```

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativemodels.html#qstringlist-based-model),

> A model may be a simple QStringList, which provides the contents of
>   the list via the modelData role.

**Edit #1:**

I get the warning `ReferenceError: myModel is not defined` when I am working with your C++ code.

Maybe it's my fault because I don't have the whole code, but in any case here you have a different way to interact with QML Objects:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QStringList>

#include <qqmlengine.h>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStringList s;
    s.append("1");
    s.append("2");
    s.append("2");
    s.append("2");
    s.append("2");
    s.append("3");

    QQuickView view;

    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(s));

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:view.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need the `model` property, but you have different ways of updating the `ListView.` My code avoids the warning, but surely you will find your own solution. Happy coding!